# Sharing custom images within an organization in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, google-cloud-iam, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to share a custom image in GCP between projects in the organization.

1) Project A

2) project B

All my custom Images are in project A.

I would like to share images of project A to Project B

As per the documentation I ran the following command to share images to project B

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding projecta --member serviceAccount:xxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/compute.imageUser
```

I am using Terraform to provision the instances. In terraform, I am specifying to take the image from project A.

```
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "projects/project_A/global/images/custom_image"
    }
  }
```

I am getting the below error

```
Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.images.useReadOnly' permission for 'projects/project_A/global/images/custom_image', forbidden
```

Can someone please help me out....

Answer (score 2):

I guess the documentation is for Deployment Manager, not for Terraform, the command you run granted the role to service account `xxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`, but Terraform is not using that account by default.

You need to make sure Terraform has enough permission. [You may supply `xxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` to Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials) or create a new service account for Terraform and grant `roles/compute.imageUser` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You've just done the first step which is [granti an service account a proper permissions to share your images across your organisation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#mig_all_images_access). The `roles/compute.imageUser` role is required to do it.

Your Terraform config also looks OK (you have to make sure the self_link to your image is correct (refer to [this documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#source) to make sure `image` value in Terraform config is OK).

Also make sure you're [providing proper service account credentials to Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/getting_started.html#adding-credentials) as stated in @Ken Hung's answer.